# Javascript detect overflowing elements

Tags: javascript, html, overflow

I am building a script that splits content into columns. This is how the script should work:

1. I have a series of fixed size divs with overflow turned off
2. I write content into the first div
3. Using Javascript I detect where the content is overflowing.
4. I cut out the content from that point to the end
5. I write this content to the next div
6. Then I do steps 3-6 until the content no longer overflows

This is all great in theory, but I don't know how to detect what element is overflowing in a div.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use CSS? Put a width and height on the divs. Leave overflow alone in this case. There is no way of knowing where the content is overflowing with JavaScript. Fonts are not really standardized.

Comment: I need it to work on IE 7 and above.

Comment: You could use `Element.value.length` or `Element.innerHTML.length` to get the character count, then do some division and create your divs.

Comment: @PHPglue—that approach doesn't work because proportional fonts mean different characters require a different amount of space and also you don't know where wrapping or word breaks have occurred. It also may be different for different browsers on different platforms (e.g. Windows lays out fonts differently to Mac).

Comment: This can be achieved to some extent by making overflow scroll and seeing if scroll bars are added. If they are, remove them again and start putting content into the new div from the last word onward. If you turn scroll on then off again before the function ends, the user will not see them appear then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaking with javascript code is not good. **Using CSS is faster and more reliable.**

But if really really you need, I want to help you with next code.

HTML

```
<div>abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz </div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Javascript with jQuery

```
var restText = "";
$("div").each(function() {
    var el = $(this), w = el.width(), baseText = el.text(), tbox;
    if (baseText === "") {
        baseText = restText;
    }
    el.html("<span>"+baseText+"</span>");
    tbox = el.children("span");
    for (var i = baseText.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (tbox.width() > w) {
            tbox.text(baseText.substring(0, i-1));
        } else {
            restText = baseText.substring(i);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/y53yen02/